# Installing the correct environment for Angular with Compass and all other Node dependencies

Tags: ruby, angularjs, compass-sass, gruntjs

I am just trying to make a local development environment that isn't on my work computer, and I keep getting an error:

> Warning: Errno::ENOENT on line 441 of /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/pathname.rb: No such file or directory - /Users/johnpett/Desktop/Node/app/bower_components
>   Run with --trace to see the full backtrace Use --force to continue.

I have installed all the Ruby parts and Yeoman to build the app scaffold, but I can't seem to run the 'grunt server' command without throwing up this error.

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite clear, a grunt-plugin require that file...
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/pathname.rb
Anyway ruby components are needed usually if you plan to use compass, if not, you can comment the "compass" sub-task in the "server" task in Gruntfile.js

Comment: I do need Compass, but I have installed that and Ruby, which is why I am unsure this isn't working.

Comment: well, first thing to do is check if that file exists.. have you installed version 1.8?

Comment: Just reinstalled everything from scratch and it works! Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Your folder was surely not called `bower_components` at that time. I guess you used yeoman.
In your compass task config you should have modified `bower_components`.